# Checking for "true" response in JavaScript form Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

In response to an Ajax request my php file either `echo true` or `echo false`. In my JavaScript file I want to call one of two functions depending on the response. I displayed the content of `xmlhttp.responseText` and found it to be 1 so I tried

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1)
{
  funcA()
}
else
{
  funcB()
}
```

and

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText === 1)
{
  funcA()
}
else
{
  funcB()
}
```

but `funcB()` always gets called. What should I check for in the JavaScript if statement if I want `funcA()` to be called when true is the response?

Ok so one answer says to convert the integer to a string, another says to parse the string as an integer. I tried and both work, is one method faster than the other?

**There's times I strongly believe questions shouldn't be downvoted and this is one of them.** A short coming I didn't see is that if I ever try to output something in my PHP page (e.g. `echo()` or `var_dump()`) then this JavaScript will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Since it's text, you should probably be comparing to `"1"` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If php is echoing back a boolean you should be able to just check the response in the condition like this:

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText) {
    funcA();
else {
    funcB();
}
```

The condition is automatically casted to a boolean value for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an exact match when your `responseText` will be a string. You can either typecast responseText to integer (via `parseInt()`) or do a loose check (replace === with ==). Either of the solutions will fix the problem.

Comment: I don't think what you said is right, I have to do *both* type cast and use == not ===